# ¿ Spring Tool Suite 3.7.3 (JDK 7) da un error Unsupported major.minor version 52.0?

Tags: java

Necesito compilar un proyecto desarrollado en Java 7, para eso necesito usar Spring Tool Suite ver. 3.7.3 pues es la última versión que salió para jdk7, pero me da un error:

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

aunque todo esta configurado para java 7 incluyendo variable JAVA_HOME, lo único que pienso que pudiera ser es la versión de maven...

Apreciaría cualquier ayuda al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

El error indica que durante el tiempo de compilación está utilizando un JDK más alto y un JDK más bajo durante el tiempo de ejecución.

La **versión 52.0** corresponde a **Java SE 8**

de acuerdo al mensaje de error:

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0?

estas usando un JDK menor (jdk7) y requiere uno de versión mayor.

Answer (score 0):

Ese error se obtiene cuando ejecutas una aplicación con una versión del JDK/JRE menor a la que utilizaste para compilarlo.

En otras palabras, al parecer estás intentando ejecutar la aplicación con un JDK cuya versión es inferior a Java 8, cuya versión de archivos de clase es la 52.

Para solucionarlo recompila todo el proyecto con el JDK que deseas luego ejecutar tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Valida en tu IDE la configuracion que tienes, que sea la misma versión el ide como tu proyecto. Que el compilador de tu IDE, P.E Eclipse, (Windows>preferences>java>compiler) se al el mismo que el de tu proyecto (Clic derecho sobre el proyecto, propiedades>Java Compiler)